# Gorethink Insert Issue

Tags: go, rethinkdb

```
var data = map[string]interface{}{
    "json_received": [
        {
        "ezpOrderId":  "ezp_123",
        "firstName":  "Vasanth",
        "lastName":  "K",
        "orderDesc":  "Sample"
        }
    ] 
    "created_on":  "03-22-2015",
    "status":  "1"
}


result, err := r.Table("order_json").Insert(data).RunWrite(session)
```

When i m tried to run this program i got the error as "missing operand" after "json_received":[ line.

Please help me to insert the data variable in rethink db via go programming..

Comment: Each entry to the map should end with commas including the last one.    
What is "json_received"? Is it a string? if so you need quotes surrounding it.

Answer (score 2):

Go does not support json literals like you are trying to do.

Here's a fixed version ([on Play](http://play.golang.org/p/dKlbCDxWOu)).

Notice that for all sub structures, you must declare the type when creating it.
You were trying to make json_recieved to be a list of json objects, so I used `[]map[string]interface{}`.

And, as others have pointed out, multi-line map/list literals must have a comma after each line, as in: `orderDesc`, `status`.

package main

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var data = map[string]interface{}{
        "json_received": []map[string]interface{}{
            {
                "ezpOrderId": "ezp_123",
                "firstName":  "Vasanth",
                "lastName":   "K",
                "orderDesc":  "Sample",
            },
        },
        "created_on": "03-22-2015",
        "status":     "1",
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", data)
    //result, err := r.Table("order_json").Insert(data).RunWrite(session)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing comma after json_received array

```
"json_received": [
        {
        "ezpOrderId":  "ezp_123",
        "firstName":  "Vasanth",
        "lastName":  "K",
        "orderDesc":  "Sample"
        }
    ] , //<--
```